# Facebook recommendations multi domain

Tags: facebook, plugins

I want to write a page and want to use facebook recommendations plugins. And I want to get recommends from lots of separate domains. I check the tutorial but it can only get data from 1 domain each iframe. So if I want to get from 10 domains, I need 10 iframe? 10 connections? Is there better way for that.

Sorry if my English is bad.

Answer (score 1):

The site parameter allows you add multible domains with comma seperated values.  examples below for shawnsspace.com, anotherfeed.com, walmart.com

***Refer to Attribues - site - a comma separated list of domains to show recommendations for. The XFBML version defaults to the current domain.***

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

### xfbml

```
<fb:recommendations site="shawnsspace.com, anotherfeed.com, walmart.com" width="300" height="900" header="true"></fb:recommendations>
```

### html5

```
<div class="fb-recommendations" data-site="shawnsspace.com, anotherfeed.com, walmart.com" data-width="300" data-height="900" data-header="true"></div>
```

### iframe

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?site=shawnsspace.com%2C+anotherfeed.com%2C+walmart.com&amp;width=300&amp;height=900&amp;header=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;linktarget=_blank&amp;border_color&amp;font&amp;appId=148744491883305" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:900px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```